# How to take a value from "link to" in Photo Gallery Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, photo-gallery

I would like to take a value from input "link to" in Photo Gallery by PHP and put it in `<a>` tag. Something like this:

```
$gal_id = (int) $gallery[ $i ];
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url( $gal_id ) ) . '"</a>
```

but instead of `wp_get_attachment_url( $gal_id )` I want my link from "link to".

Comment: What do you mean by "link to"?

Comment: When I click on a photo in Photo Gallery, there are fields to fill like: URL, Title, Caption, Alt text, Description, Link to, Link target. 
I would like to enter a link to "Link to", and then using php to retrieve this value.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14773/retrieving-a-custom-link-on-an-attachment

Comment: I prefer to not update Link URL on image but take a value from a field "link to" .